# How to unit test a static property?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, static

I have a `ConferenceNumberDirectory` that has a `build` function which parses a JSON file to create static Arrays of `ConferenceNumber` objects. I want to unit test this function.

I created a unit test using a smaller JSON file to test this but my tests are failing as the test values are simply being appended on to the actual values.
My real values amount to 56 entries for the `ConferenceNumberDirectory.att` array, but when I run my tests these values are still here and my test values (13 entries) are appended on to the original array. How do I test my static properties without poisoning my them with the test data? In previous commits my unit test `ConferenceNumberDirectory.att` property and the actual one were separate entities, I don't know what's happening here (I have not changed my test class since this commit).

```
class ConferenceNumberDirectory {

static var countryNumbers = [Any]()
static var att = [ConferenceNumber]()
static var arkadin = [ConferenceNumber]()
static var webex = [ConferenceNumber]()
static var zoom = [ConferenceNumber]()

   static func build(from rootJSONArray: [Any]?) {

do {
        guard let rootJSONArray = rootJSONArray else {
            throw SerializationError.missing("JSON Root")
        }

        for entry in rootJSONArray {
            guard let dictionary = entry as? [String: Any] else {
                throw SerializationError.missing("JSON Root")
            }
            guard let isoCode = dictionary["ISO Code"] as? String else {
                throw SerializationError.missing("isoCode")
            }
            guard let country = dictionary["Country"] as? String else {
                throw SerializationError.missing("country")
            }

            if let attTollNumbers = try self.extractNumbers(from: dictionary, forKey: "AT&T toll") {
                ConferenceNumberDirectory.att.append(contentsOf: attTollNumbers.map{ConferenceNumber(ISO: isoCode, country: country, number: $0, provider: ConferenceProvider.att, toll: true) })
            }
            print(ConferenceNumberDirectory.att.count)
            if let attTollFreeNumbers = try self.extractNumbers(from: dictionary, forKey: "AT&T toll-free") {
                ConferenceNumberDirectory.att.append(contentsOf: attTollFreeNumbers.map{ConferenceNumber(ISO: isoCode, country: country, number: $0, provider: ConferenceProvider.att, toll: false)})
            }
            if let arkadinTollNumbers = try self.extractNumbers(from: dictionary, forKey: "Arkadin toll") {
                ConferenceNumberDirectory.arkadin.append(contentsOf: arkadinTollNumbers.map{ConferenceNumber(ISO: isoCode, country: country, number: $0, provider: ConferenceProvider.arkadin, toll: true) })
            }
            if let arkadinTollFreeNumbers = try self.extractNumbers(from: dictionary, forKey: "Arkadin toll-free") {
                ConferenceNumberDirectory.arkadin.append(contentsOf: arkadinTollFreeNumbers.map{ConferenceNumber(ISO: isoCode, country: country, number: $0, provider: ConferenceProvider.arkadin, toll: false) })
            }
            if let webexTollNumbers = try self.extractNumbers(from: dictionary, forKey: "Webex toll") {
                ConferenceNumberDirectory.webex.append(contentsOf: webexTollNumbers.map{ConferenceNumber(ISO: isoCode, country: country, number: $0, provider: ConferenceProvider.webex, toll: true) })
            }
            if let webexTollFreeNumbers = try self.extractNumbers(from: dictionary, forKey: "Webex toll-free") {
                ConferenceNumberDirectory.webex.append(contentsOf: webexTollFreeNumbers.map{ConferenceNumber(ISO: isoCode, country: country, number: $0, provider: ConferenceProvider.webex, toll: false) })
            }
            if let zoomTollNumbers = try self.extractNumbers(from: dictionary, forKey: "Zoom toll") {
                ConferenceNumberDirectory.zoom.append(contentsOf: zoomTollNumbers.map{ConferenceNumber(ISO: isoCode, country: country, number: $0, provider: ConferenceProvider.zoom, toll: true) })
            }
        }
    }
    catch let error {
        print(error)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your properties are `static`, they live throughout the execution of the code - no actual instance of your class is needed for them to remain in memory. That's why `static` properties should be used with caution. You can read more about `static` properties in Swift [in the docs, under "Type properties"](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html).

As to your problem at hand :
You should leverage the `tearDown()` method in your test class, and restore those properties to their empty state. `tearDown()` is a method in `XCTestCase` class, which is run after each test case - you can override it to provide custom cleanup for your tests. A simple example :

```
override func tearDown() {
    ConferenceNumberDirectory.att = []()
    super.tearDown()
}
```

Edit:
To setup the enivronment for tests, you can override a similar method :

```
override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()
    ConferenceNumberDirectory.att = []()
}
```

This method is run before each test case is run. I'd highly recommend reading through [`XCTest` documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest)

Comment: Tricky thing is this method is called in my appdelegate `application.(didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` function so the real data is created before the test data.

Comment: Ah, I see. In an ideal world this app startup code shouldn't be included in tests, but we do not live in ideal world. Anyhow - there is a similar method you can override to prepare your class for testing. See my edit above.

Comment: What of we are using private static var? :(